# Monkey patching multiple class members in a loop in python

Tags: python, python-unittest

I want to patch multiple methods of a class at once in a loop, in order to modify how a class works for tests in all modules.

I think `object.assign` from javascript would do something similar.

This works:

```py
class A:
  def foo1(self):
    print("a")
  def foo2(self):
    print("a")

class B:
  def foo1(self):
    print("b")
  def foo2(self):
    print("b")

A.foo1 = B.foo1
A.foo2 = B.foo2
A().foo1()  # prints "b"
A().foo2()  # prints "b"
```

What I would like to do this in a loop to avoid having to specify each member individually.

Answer (score 0):

The following program will filter the class attributes and methods, and will exclude the replacement of private methods and all attributes.

```py
import collections
from types import FunctionType

class A:
  def foo1(self):
    print("a")
  def foo2(self):
    print("a")

class B:
  a = 1
  def foo1(self):
    print("b")
  def foo2(self):
    print("b")


def patch_class(original, replacement):
    for key, val in replacement.__dict__.items():
        if key.startswith("_") or not isinstance(val, FunctionType):
            continue
        setattr(original, key, val)


patch_class(A, B)
A().foo1()  # prints "b"
A().foo2()  # prints "b"
```

Answer (score -1):

`vars` returns all the methods, and `setattr` and `getattr` can write and read them based on their string name.

Certain members like `__dict__` can't be replaced, so it is wrapped in try/except.

```py
def patch_class(original, replacement):
    """Replaces all methods in original with the ones in replacement."""
    for member in vars(replacement).keys():
        try:
            target = getattr(replacement, member)
            setattr(original, member, target)
            # or:
            # patch.object(original, member, target).__enter__()
            # type.__setattr__(original, member, target)
            print("monkey-patched", member)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"could not monkey-patch {member}: {e.__class__.__name__} {e}")

class A:
  def foo1(self):
    print("a")
  def foo2(self):
    print("a")

class B:
  def foo1(self):
    print("b")
  def foo2(self):
    print("b")

patch_class(A, B)

A().foo1()  # prints "b"
A().foo2()  # prints "b"
```